# where to find graphql graphene django api tutorial for basic

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer, graphene-django

I have Django jwt script which is for graphene and when I write this installed backend creates user but I don't understand how to make registration form to fill field and send like this any small explained or documentation cant find ? thanks

```
mutation {
  register(
    email: "email",
    username: "user",
    password1: "1234f56super",
    password2: "1234f56super",
  ) {
    success,
    errors,
    token,
    refreshToken
  }
}
```